Why does the ShareLink not open a share sheet? (iOS 17.4)
I have a problem: I'm trying to open a share sheet from an alert, but the share sheet just does not open.
import SwiftUI

struct DocumentView: View {
    // ...
    
    @State private var newShare: Bool = false
    @State private var newShareName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // ...
        }
        .alert("New share", isPresented: $newShare) {
            TextField("Name", text: $newShareName)
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
            ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://www.demo.com/")!) {
                Text("Share")
            }
        } message: {
            Text("...")
        }
    }
}

I did shorten some parts of the code so it's easier to read. Maybe you guys can help. I do appreciate it.

import SwiftUI

struct DocumentView: View {
    @State private var newShare: Bool = false
    @State private var newShareName: String = ""
    @State private var showShareSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var shareItem: URL? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button("Create New Share") {
                newShare = true
            }
        }
        .alert("New share", isPresented: $newShare) {
            TextField("Name", text: $newShareName)
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
            Button("Share") {
                shareItem = URL(string: "https://www.demo.com/")
                showShareSheet = true
            }
        } message: {
            Text("...")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet, onDismiss: {
            shareItem = nil
        }) {
            if let item = shareItem {
                ShareSheet(activityItems: [item])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var activityItems: [Any]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {}
}

struct DocumentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DocumentView()
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The ShareLink component should be placed directly inside a View and not within an alert. If you want to use inside alert try to use UIActivityViewController as Presentable.

Every code snippet I've read so far included self.present(...), but that throws Value of type 'DocumentView' has no member 'present'. Btw., I need to call this inside of a Task, cause I need to call an async function. Do you have any Idea what I did wrong?
